# AWS route 53 configured to point to Elastic BeanStalk URL

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I'm a bit confused on how the Elastic BeanStalk url works.  From what I understand Elastic BeanStalk is just a management layer.  Yet I have I have a route 53 alias which seem to point to the URL section of an Elastic Beanstalk environment url, which in turn has a load balancer.  I'm not sure/confused on how the request can go from route53 into an Elastic Beanstalk url, shouldn't it go to the load balancer?

Comment: both beanstalk and load balancer resolve the same IP and traffic does to the same place.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more, I'm a bit confused.  What do you mean b "resolve the same IP  and traffic"?